# VueJS method json response to selectbox?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a VueJS component, now I'm getting from JSON response which I want to export into a html select box.

My VueJS method:

```
getTaskList() {
    axios.get('/api/v1/tasklist').then(response => {
        this.taskList = this.data.taskList;
    });
}
```

I found example in [VueJS documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html) but there is still the problem with method...

How can I export this response into a selectbox, I know how to work with `v-for`, but I don't know exactly how to initialize this data in HTML (with v-bind, or something like that)?

Comment: What are you getting exactly from `/api/v1/tasklist`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what's in the `taskList` items but you can simply bind those data in `option` tags :

```
<select v-model="selectedTask">
  <option v-for="task in taskList" :key="task.id" :value="task.value">{{ task.label }}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I know this, but where I have to define v-model="selectedTask" in JS code?

Comment: Solved, I called this function in mounted area and not works everything (this. getTaskList())

Comment: You could even call this method in the `created` hook, so your data will be ready as soon as possible (you don't need to wait for the element to be mounted to load those data). Sorry I didn't understand your question in the first place.